# Add margin top or padding top to a series of display inline div tags

Tags: html, css, inline, padding

I'm trying to set my example code so that the second row isn't so cramped at the top. I cannot split these into 2 rows so I need a way to add some kind of padding to the top of each div so there is a bit of breathing space.

Below is the code I have tried and I've also added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3kMc/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
     <div class="item red">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .container{
     width:500px;
 }
 .item{
     width:90px; 
     height:20px;
     display:inline;
     margin-right:10px;
     padding-top:15px;
 }
 .red{
     background-color:#B222222;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margin, among many other CSS properties, doesn't work on objects with `display: inline`.

Use `inline-block` instead, or `display: block` together with  `float: left`.

Comment: cheers for the answer, this one seems a lot more flexible than display:inline block;

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block;` on the `.item` `div`s.

### Demo

```
 .item{
     width:90px; 
     height:20px;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-right:10px;
     margin-top:15px;
 }
```

Margins don't work on non-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add `line-height` in the `.container` `div` to give some space, example:

```
.container {
  width:500px;
  line-height:2;
}
```

Change the value '2' to your requirements.

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aStg/).